# azure variable initialization in logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

when we press enter in variable value text box it will show newline only( \n ) 
where as in notepad or text editor it will consider \r\n (CR|LF carriage return with new line feed) is this expected behaviour?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a normal behavior in logic app. If we press enter, the value will show a new line. We can see the enter will be considered as `\n`(but not `\r\n`) if we want to do some operation on it.
[image]

[image]